# How to check a user's database attributes after the session is created for that user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, session

I want to store certain elements of the user in session from the database.  Are there any methods that I can use to access these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   **Maybe you asking for this only**

     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.
     ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString);
     da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from User", con);
     dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["Name"] = dt.Rows[0]["Username"].ToString();
        Session["Email"] = dt.Rows[0]["UserEmail"].ToString();
    }  
 //Name like ["Username"].. is of your database column name..//
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohee for accepted it as answer and making it beneficial for others too.